# How to extract my 'onerror' inline JS out of my html from multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flask

I have a flask app and there are some `<img>` elements in different templates in which I placed the following inline js to prevent an eventual broken image in case the proper one isn't found:

```
onerror="if (this.src != '../static/images/default.png') this.src = '../static/images/default.png';"
```

This works, but it's not at all elegant, and would like to extract it to my scripts file to avoid inline JS.

How can I do this, knowing that there are multiple elements with the class `user-picture` and `perfume-picture` respectively, and that user-picture and perfume-picture use a different fallback image?

Thanks!!

**UPDATE**:

Now attempting the solution below, as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img").each(function () {
        this.onerror = function () {
            if ($(this).attr("class") === "user-picture") {
                $(this).attr("src", "../images/avatar.png");
            } else if ($(this).attr("class") === "perfume-picture") {
                $(this).attr("src", "../images/generic.jpg");
            }
        };
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work, although it makes a lot of sense.

Below there are two examples of my `img` elements, for reference:

```
<img class="perfume-picture" src="{{ perfume.picture }}" loading="lazy" width=225 height=300 alt="Perfume">

<img class="user-picture" src="{{ author["profilePicture"] }}" loading="lazy" width=100 height=100 alt="Avatar">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this: loop through all images using `each()`, set an `onerror` event handler for them and check the class of a broken image to set the corresponding fallback image.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("img").each(function() {
     this.onerror = function() {
       if ($(this).hasClass("user-picture")) {
          $(this).attr("src", "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/cecece/fff&text=user");
       }    
       else if ($(this).hasClass("perfume-picture")) {
          $(this).attr("src", "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/cecece/fff&text=perfume");
       }
     }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="user-picture" src="test.jpg"/>
<img class="perfume-picture" src="dummy.jpg"/>
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff"/>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! This really makes a lot of sense, but it doesn't work for me. I just updated my question, perhaps you can spot what I am doing wrong? Thanks very much!!

Comment: @GuillermoBrachetta Do you have the function inside a $(document).ready(function() {}); ? I've just updated my answer with that, maybe this could be the reason why it's not working for you.

Comment: I did put it inside (also updated my question with the current status) but... not yet working...

Comment: @GuillermoBrachetta Can you put a console message inside the function to check if it gets called? Maybe it has to do with the image path which could then be excluded as possible issue.

Comment: I get a console message immediately after the onerror, but not inside the if or the else

Comment: @GuillermoBrachetta What do you get if you check for the class in the console message after the onerror, e.g. with console.message("error " + $(this).attr("class")); ?

Comment: @GuillermoBrachetta If the images have multiple classes, this approach can't work as the multiple class names don't match the single class names. I've just adjusted my answer with an approach to use hasClass() which should work for you.

Comment: @GuillermoBrachetta Glad that I was able to help :)

Comment: Absolutely! And I can get rid of the $(document).ready. Many thanks, you saved me!

Comment: @GuillermoBrachetta Actually you should keep the $(document).ready to make sure the function gets executed once jQuery is loaded. It can work without it but it's better to keep it to be on the safe side.

Comment: Will do so! Thanks again!

Comment: Strangely it works most of the times, I'd say 70% of the times, but not infallibly for some reason. Maybe my localhost? I'll deploy and test remotely